# Slow performance with Guzzle6 vs curl

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle 6 to make multiple requests over network in PHP 7.2

My problem is that comparing with a curl command with Guzzle it takes twice as long : 200ms with curl vs 400-500ms with Guzzle.

Do you have any ideea what would be the problem?

Comment: It would be useful to show us the exact code snippets you're comparing. It might not be curl or guzzle at all but rather some subtle detail you've missed.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps Guzzle picks the incorrect handler for the client? Check if it is the CurlMultiHandler and not some other handler that might impact performance.

https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/de6f1e58e735754b888649495ed4cb9ae3b19589/src/Utils.php#L77-L106

Comment: correct here is how to add handlers
https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-add-custom-curl-options